# HTML table export into MS-Excel without asking for save location using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a HTML table in velocity template. I want to export the HTML table data to excel using jQuery. I am using below script, it work fine but save excel file in download folder without asking user where he want to save. Mean can not open save as dialogbox. Can any one tell me the any property or missing code line for that dialogbox, when user click on export to excel button he first chose custom path for saving file.
Thanks in advance

```
var uri = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64,'
    , template = '<html xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"><head><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml><x:ExcelWorkbook><x:ExcelWorksheets><x:ExcelWorksheet><x:Name>{worksheet}</x:Name><x:WorksheetOptions><x:DisplayGridlines/></x:WorksheetOptions></x:ExcelWorksheet></x:ExcelWorksheets></x:ExcelWorkbook></xml><![endif]--></head><body><table>{table}</table></body></html>'
    , base64 = function (s) { return window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(s))) }
    , format = function (s, c) { return s.replace(/{(\w+)}/g, function (m, p) { return c[p]; }) }
var ctx = { worksheet: fileName || 'Worksheet', table: htmlTable }
document.getElementById("dlink").href = uri + base64(format(template, ctx));
document.getElementById("dlink").download = "MyExcelFile.xls";
document.getElementById("dlink").click();
```

Comment: sorry forgot to add about dlink.
it is dummy html a tag. <a id="dlink"  style="display:none;"></a>

Comment: Try it on Firefox : I think this issue is relative to your browser configuration. For example : Chrome does not answer the user to choose target folder for his download, by default it will use the download folder

Comment: try it on Firefox @tony but not working.